# Adding comma after first word in column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table called `people` and a column called `NAME` which has last first middle (if exists) . so SMITH JOHN J  I'd like to add a comma after first word so it updates to SMITH, JOHN J

I tried running this but it blew up:

```
update people
set name = (CHARINDEX(' ', 0), 0, ',')
```

I know I'm close but it's eluding me :(

Comment: Why not using separate columns for first and last name?

Comment: so you are calling a function CHARINDEX and passing a space but not passing what to search. Then you have that inside `()` -- why would `()` -- mybe you are trying to call REPLACE?  REPLACE would also need a parameter of what to replace.

Comment: Make sure you consider those people who have last names like "Baron Cohen", "Bonham Carter", or "Vaughan Williams".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STUFF()` along with `CHARINDEX()` and `LEFT()` for this:

```
update people
set name = STUFF(name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',name )-1,LEFT(name ,CHARINDEX(' ',name )-1)+', ')
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',name) > 0
```

Might add a `WHERE` to ensure there is a space in the name so it doesn't error, or a `CASE` expression.

Could also use `REPLACE()` with `CHARINDEX()` and `LEFT()`:

```
REPLACE(name,LEFT(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)-1),LEFT(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)-1)+',')
```

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion as well, you just answered right before I submitted.

Comment: @hart CO the first one worked like a boss. Thank you!